# Correct use of template with a class member function

Tags: c++, templates

the concept of templates is quite difficult to grasp quickly. I need a class member  function to iterate over vector of any objects and print them all out. Can I do this with using templates? I.e.:

```
    void SomeClass::printAll(std::vector< any type here> array) {
      for (auto & o : array) {
        std::cout << o << std::end;
    
      }   
    }
```

If this is possible in C++, how would I define it in the header and implementation files, I dare guess the syntax might be different.

Many thanks in advance for helping with this naive questions.

Comment: In general you need to to declare and define template in the header file. So in your .h you will have something like: `template<typename T> void printAll(std::vector<T> array) {...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to grasp any non-trivial topic *quickly* is difficult. Just don't do it, but go slowly. That also means not trying to understand more than one thing at a time. I don't know why that function has to be member of a class. Make it a free function:

```
template <typename T>
void printAll(const std::vector<T>& vect) {
    for (const auto& o : vect) {
        std::cout << o << "\n";   
    }   
}
```

Don't pass by value when you can pass by const reference. I would prefer `\n` here rather than `std::endl` (not `std::end`) because `std::endl` flushes the stream. Choose names carefully, a `std::vector` is not an array.

The above will only work with vectors, but it can be more flexible for example by passing iterators:

```
template <typename IT>
void printAll(IT begin, IT end) {
    for ( ; begin != end; ++begin) {
        std::cout << *begin << "\n";   
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, caring about the difference between `'\n'` and `std::endl` makes sense only in performance-critical code parts. I mostly prefer `std::endl` simply because it is more readable in the source code.

Comment: @DanielLangr I prefer to make the one that is fine in performance cirtical and in non-perforamnce critical the default, and as I am more used to it I consider it more readable, though I agree that I put too much weight on this when it is matter of style to some extend. Changed the wording

Comment: Thank you, that definitely helps. Quick answer is a temporary solution, I absolutely agree, this doesn't bring much proficiency. I will take a closer look.